# Dynamic use of a class method defined in a Cython extension module

Tags: python, methods, cython

I would like to use the C implementation of a class method (generated from [Cython](http://www.cython.org/)) if it is present, or use its Python equivalent if the C extension is not present. I first tried this:

```
class A(object):
    try:
        import c_ext
        method = c_ext.optimized_method
    except ImportError:
        def method(self):
            return "foo"
```

Where optimized_method is a function defined in a [Cython](http://www.cython.org/) module:

```
def optimized_method(self):
    return "fasterfoo"
```

But this doesn't work:

```
>>> A().method()
exceptions.TypeError: optimized_method() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

The only way I found to make this work is:

```
class A(object):
    def method(self):
        try:
            import c_ext
            return c_ext.optimized_method(self)
        except ImportError:
            pass
        return "foo"
```

But checking for the module's presence at each function call seems quite suboptimal... Why isn't my first approach working ?

[edit] : added [Cython](http://www.cython.org/) module's contents

Comment: I'd suggest that you show how c_ext.optimized_method was defined for the sake of clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I just found the answer...

The problem comes from the way Cython [wraps the functions it exports](http://docs.cython.org/docs/limitations.html#behaviour-of-class-scopes): every method is unbound regardless from where it is referenced.

The solution is to explicitly declare a bound method:

```
class A(object):
    def method(self):
        return "foo"

try:
    import c_ext
    import types
    A.method = types.MethodType(c_ext.optimized_method, None, A)
except ImportError:
    pass
```